# Le « casque de réalité virtuelle » etc. : virtuellement un casque ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, terminologie, lexique

[image]
<sub><sub>À gauche, un *casque de réalité virtuelle* (*VR Headset*) ; au centre, un *masque de plongée* ; à droite, une *lunette de sécurité*...</sub></sub>

---

On a bien des termes comme [*casque VR*](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=vr%20headset&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs)/[*de réalité virtuelle*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casque_de_r%C3%A9alit%C3%A9_virtuelle) ou [*de réalité de synthèse*](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/terme/INFO719?from=list&francetermeSearchTerme=virtual%20reality&francetermeSearchDomaine=0), équipement « composé » principalement du [*visiocasque*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8357145) (stéréoscopique), ce casque à vision stéréoscopique etc.. qui « procure à l'utilisateur une perception en relief des images de synthèse générées par l'ordinateur et une immersion dans le monde virtuel » (GDT). Par ailleurs on a le [*masque de plongée*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8435507) et les [*lunettes de sécurité*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=2070684), voire des [*lunettes stéréoscopiques*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8873071) ou *3D*...

Le [*casque*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/casque), ce peut être dans le domaine des technologies un « appareil rappelant la forme du casque » (TLFi), par exemple « *le casque téléphonique; casque à écouteurs*. Appareil récepteur muni de deux écouteurs reliés entre eux par un support qui enserre la tête un peu à la manière d'un casque » (TLFi). On glisse de ce qui rappelle la forme à ce qui enserre un peu à la manière... d'un casque. Il est sanglé à la tête ; il se porte à la tête dans le sens qu'il ne se porte pas au bras, par exemple, mais il n'est certainement pas plus *sur* la tête de l'utilisateur qu'un bandeau ne le serait. Enfin sa forme rappelle celle d'autres équipements qui procurent une forme ou une autre d'étanchéité ou d'isolement du champ de vision pour ainsi dire, mais qu'on ne désigne pas pour autant par casque (*masque, lunette*). Si bien que je me questionne sur sa pertinence, son utilité, et sa cohérence au lexique alors que les objets changent ; est-ce toujours adapté à la réalité...

---

- **Un casque est-il composé d'un casque.** Pourquoi trouverait-on l'[hypéronymie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperonymie) présentée dans l'ébauche d'article sur [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casque_de_r%C3%A9alit%C3%A9_virtuelle) à l'effet qu'un *casque de réalité virtuelle* est composé d'un *visiocasque stéréoscopique*, utile ou redondante ; ne serait-il pas plus juste de dire qu'un *système* de réalité virtuelle/de synthèse est composé d'un *casque...* ou d'un *visiocasque* etc., ou s'agit-il d'une différence entre le langage courant et technique ?
- **S'agit-il toujours d'un casque ou sinon de quoi ?** Pourquoi trouverait-on ou non toujours utile, pertinent ou cohérent
  l'emploi du mot *casque* pour désigner ce genre d'appareil ; le casque est-il toujours productif dans ce domaine ; autrement quel terme trouverait-on le plus clair, usuel : masque , lunette... dispositif... *visière (numérique de réalité de synthèse)*, *visiomodule (de réalité virtuelle)*... un mot latin avec un mot grec... immersif, de réalité virtuelle, de réalité de synthèse, de visualisation ; incidemment le terme *casque* serait-il aussi clair ou aussi flou que le terme [*gant (numérique)*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8367492) ne le serait par rapport à *contrôleur de mouvement* ?
- **Peut-on illustrer dans une phrase complète** quel terme générique
  (premier point) utilise-t-on le cas échéant avec quel terme et complément du nom sélectionné précédemment (deuxième point) pour couramment expliquer ce dont il s'agit ?

Comment: *"Songez-y, la plupart des grandes excentricités de la mode, excentricités si frappantes qu'elles se perfectionnent jusqu'au lieu commun (la casquette entre autres), furent, à l'origine, quelque ruse d'individu célèbre pour masquer une imperfection...*" C'est Cocteau. Je ne l'avais jamais tenu pour un grand visionnaire... Il n'empêche! Sur ce coup, il avait deviné un truc. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

> Un casque est-il composé d'un casque?

Rappelons-nous que le terme `casque de réalité virtuelle` nous a été apporté et popularisé par les média se concentrant sur les technologies. Ceux-ci ont une forte tendance à simplifier la langue française: anglicismes, hyperonymie, asyndètes, etc.

Donc oui, on *devrait* dire `système de réalité virtuelle` au lieu de `casque de réalité virtuelle` car ce dernier n'est qu'un composant et c'est donc plus *techniquement correct*, mais c'est très peu idiomatique. A éviter dans le langage courant, donc.

> S'agit-il toujours d'un casque?

Oui. L'expression `casque de réalité virtuelle` est acceptée dans le langage commun, donc la définition de `casque` est désormais étendue. La signification des mots évoluent en fonction du temps (et surtout dans le domaine technologique).

Comment: Merci ! Quel niveau de transformation du casque est-il requis pour que l'usage change selon vous. Pensez-vous que si ça a la forme d'une lunette, voire éventuellement d'un implant oculaire, le mot casque tombera-t-il... connaissez-vous un exemple d'appareil dont la grosseur ou la forme dictait la base d'un mot et qui vu les progrès technologiques s'est transformé en quelque chose d'autre.  L'usage finit-il par s'intéresser à la cohérence, ou la cohérence ou l'adéquation finit-elle toujours par l'emporter par la force des choses, à votre avis ?

Comment: Je pense que c'est plutôt le contraire qui se passe le plus souvent, je pense aux objets comme le *telephone*, le *jounal*, ou l'*école*, qui se sont métamorphosés grandement au fil du temps mais qui ont gardés la même dénomination - et qui ne sont pas près de changer.

Comment: Étonnamment, certains objets/concepts ne changent pas de sens mais un nouveau mot est inventé! C'est le cas du mot *aeroplane* qui a été remplacé par *avion* au début du 20e siècle.

Comment: Je pense que casque, qui signifie originellement une protection pour la tête (étymologie: [armure de tête](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/casque)) a vu progressivement son sens être étendu à tout ce qui se porte sur la tête, la couvrant totalement ou partiellement, pour un usage technique spécifique et défini : casque de chantier, casque de réalité virtuelle... On appellera pas un chapeau un casque.